# Read only first N bytes from socket in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, buffer

```
var server = net.createServer(function(c) {
  //...
  c.on('data', function(data) {
    //The data is all data, but what if I need only first N and do not need other data, yet.
    c.write(data);
  });
  //...
};
```

Is there a way to read only defined portion of data? For example:

```
c.on('data', N, function(data) {
  //Read first N bytes
});
```

Where N is number of bytes I expect. So the callback gets only N out of M bytes.

The solution is (thanks to mscdex):

```
c.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk,
      N = 4;
  while (null !== (chunk = c.read(N))) {
    console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
  }
});
```

Comment: Who downvoted? Please, comment!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Readable streams in node v0.10+ have a [`read()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size) that allows you to request a number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a buffer where your data will only save the amount that your buffer holds.

```
var buf = Buffer(someNum)
```

Here's the documentation for the details http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_size

Comment: I get "data" Buffer as a parameter from callback. How creation of another Buffer can help?