# Using request, how to download the first N bytes and return them in a function?

Tags: node.js

I am a bit stuck and require your help.

Any idea on how do I change this downloader function (yes, I need to keep this as a function returning a buffer) making sure it **download and returns** only the first N bytes?

```js
...
async function getDataFromURL(url) {
    const options = {
        uri: url,
        gzip: true,
        encoding: null,
        method: 'GET',
    };
    let response = await request(options);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.body;
    } else {
        throw response.statusCode + " " + response.statusMessage;
    };
};
...
let downloadedData = await getDataFromURL('https://server/file');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read only first N bytes from socket in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525376/read-only-first-n-bytes-from-socket-in-node-js)

Comment: I don’t think so, as I think this solution applies to streams, whereas I need to return a buffer.
Also, if I am not mistaken, I can’t return the result as a function value in a globally accessible variable (such as `downloadedData` in my example) using callback structure in this solution ?

Comment: Why not `return response.body.substr(n)`, where `n` is the number of bytes you want to return? While that still fetches the entire request, if that's not sufficient, you may be able to use an [HTTP range request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) to request only a given number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kmoser ! I completely overlooked the [HTTP range request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) headers, and is a simple answer to my question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution thanks to @kmoser

```js
...
async function getDataFromURL(url) {
    const options = {
        uri: url,
        gzip: true,
        encoding: null,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Range': 'bytes=0-253' // Maximum number of bytes to download
        }
    };
    let response = context.request(options);
    if (response.statusCode == 206 || response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.body;
    } else {
        throw response.statusCode + " " + response.statusMessage;
    };
};
...
let downloadedData = await getDataFromURL('https://server/file');
```